# Does an ELK based SIEM need a correlation engine?

Tags: siem

We want to build a SIEM with an ELK stack, for a multi sites software company (10 locations, 10k people). Is a security specific correlation engine recommended or is it unnecessary?

As possible security dedicated correlation engines, we have identified: CorEactive/Esper, Drools, NodeBrain, Prelude, SEC. Some correlation engine [reviews](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Tiago_Cruz3/publication/275654821_A_Comparative_Study_of_Correlation_Engines_for_Security_Event_Management/links/5714eef208aebef399607096.pdf) recommend Esper as the best compromise for performance, configuration flexibility and setup easiness. But I don't know if it is a good idea to use one.

Comment: it all depends on what you want your outcomes to be

Comment: Could you be more explicit please, possibly trade-off what can be the potential outcomes of correlation engines versus Query DSL ?

Comment: This, too, is not a security question. Comparing data analysis methods is a data management concern.

Comment: Questions out of context are useless. Context is security here

Comment: Security is not a context but an application of your question.

Comment: Just flinging "security" around in your question does not make it about security. "Esper" is not security-specific but analyses *events*. If you *want* correlation in your SIEM, then add correlation engines.